# When i append html element it override click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, overriding, bind

```
this.div=$j("<div class='test' id='test"+this._x+"'>"+this.getHtml(inner)+"<a id='testa"+this._x+"''>Close</a></div>");
    this.div.hide().appendTo($j("body")).fadeIn(100);
    this.div.children("#testa"+this._x).bind('click', function(){
          alert(this._x);
   });
```

in constructor

```
this._x = x;
x++;
```

when i click testa he gives me this._x last x number
is there an override?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, JS events are tied to the element itself. If you delete and recreate an element the handlers go with it. You can either re-connect them, or look into using jQuery's [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) functionality.

Comment: Thank you for .live() functionality

Answer (score 0):

this._x in your event listener points to non existant property of  (A._x).

```
this.div=$j("<div class='test' id='test"+this._x+"'>"+this.getHtml(inner)+"<a id='testa"+this._x+"''>Close</a></div>");
    this.div.hide().appendTo($j("body")).fadeIn(100);
    var newX = this._x;
    this.div.children("#testa"+this._x).bind('click', function(){
          alert(newX);
   });
```